# How to queue "New Order" email before "New Invoice" email?

Tags: invoice, transactional-mail, order-email

I'm working on a Magento CE 1.9.2.2 install. The cron is setup and all emails are being sent.

Now when a customer completes an order and returns to the success page after making the payment he/she will receive two emails. The first email is the "New Invoice" email and the second email is the "New Order" email.

It doesn't seem very logical to receive an invoice before receiving an order confirmation. And sometimes minutes can pass before the order confirmation is sent, while the customer has already received the invoice.

So I want to change the order in which these two emails are sent. I want the **first email** to be the **"New Order"** email and the **second email** to be the **"New Invoice"** email.

Is there an easy solution to make this work or would this require complex customizations?